# Create XML from Database Dataset and Generated XSD Class C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Good day,
I need some help,
I have a dataset which I populate from my db, I also have a xsd Schema file
I need to create an xml file using the data from the db and the xsd file.

Can anyone please help me.

All the best

Comment: Use following :             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.WriteXml("Filename", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

Comment: I already have the schema file, i need to basically combine my db data and my schema to create the xml file

Comment: You don't need to write the schema, but I recommend comparing you existing schema against the generated schema.  If the two schemas are the same, then just used the generated one.  Makes code a lot simpler.

Comment: Do you possibly have a code example for me as I am very new to xml. Do my db column names have to be the same as my xml attriute names?

Answer (score 1):

You can cross reference the database names with the datatable names in you Select Query by using "as" : "Select abc as xyz from table1".   "abc" is the database name and xyz is the datatable name which will be the xml tag name.

Here is an example of writing a DataSet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");

            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", 1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mary", 2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Dick", 3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Harry", 4});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Jane", 5});

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("MySet");
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            ds.WriteXml(FILENAME, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            // or
            //ds.WriteXml(FILENAME);

        }

    }


}
```